# Stay logged while switching between domains

Tags: 8

I have two domains (domain1.com and domain2.com) for one drupal installation. In some occasions I switch between the two. When a logged in user does this he is not logged in anymore.

Search the internet I find some answers talking about a cookie domain. But this is always connected tot Drupal 7 and not Drupal 8. Is there a similar option I can use in my settings.php file to solve this problem?

Comment: Are two totally different domains or one is a subdomain of the other? In both domains do you have the same Drupal installation, are they two different Drupal or just one is a Drupal?

Comment: I have two different domains and one drupal installation.

Comment: You cannot share Cookies between two different domains. It's a security policy, not something you can affect. You should look into SSO solutions.